# create a numpy array from the minimum values in the rows of an array

Tags: python, numpy

Starting with a 2D Numpy array I would like to create a 1D array in which each value corresponds to the minimum value of each row in the 2D array.

For example if

```
dog=[[1,2],[4,3],[6,7]]
```

then I would like to create an array from

```
'dog':[1,3,6]
```

This seems like it should be easy to do, but I'm not getting it so far.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [54]: dog=[[1,2],[4,3],[6,7]]

In [55]: np.min(dog, axis=1)
Out[55]: array([1, 3, 6])
```

or, if `dog` is a NumPy array, you could call its `min` method:

```
In [57]: dog = np.array([[1,2],[4,3],[6,7]])

In [58]: dog.min(axis=1)
Out[58]: array([1, 3, 6])
```

Since `dog.shape` is (3,2), (for 3 rows, 2 columns), the `axis=1` refers to the second dimension in the shape -- the one with 2 elements. Putting `axis=1` in the call to `dog.min` tells NumPy to take the min over the `axis=1` direction, thus eliminating the axis of length 2. The result is thus of shape `(3,)`.

Answer (score 0):

Without numpy:

```
dog=[[1,2],[4,3],[6,7]] 
mins = [min(x) for x in dog]
```